# Why do both elements move when one is dragged with this function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a range slider with 2 draggable handles. It's still in the early stages and at this point I'm trying to just get the two handles moving independently when dragged.

However the problem I'm getting is if I bind the event handlers to `document` both handles move together when one is dragged. If I bind to the element passed in through the selector argument (the handle itself) then both handles move independently, but then only work when the mouse pointer is within the confines of that element which is not a nice behavior.

Here's my code. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function draggable(selector, options) {
  var options = options || {};
  let el = document.querySelector(selector);
  var mx = 0,
    my = 0;
  var dragging = false;
  var offset = [0, 0];
  var constrain = options.constrain || false;
  if (options === undefined) options = [];

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    offset = {
      x: el.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
      y: el.offsetTop - e.clientY
    };
  });
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mx = e.clientX;
    my = e.clientY;

    if (dragging) {
      if (!constrain || constrain == 'x') el.style.left = (mx + offset.x) + 'px';
      if (!constrain || constrain == 'y') el.style.top = (my + offset.y) + 'px';
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    dragging = false;
  });
}
var min = new draggable('#min', {
  constrain: 'x'
});
var max = new draggable('#max', {
  constrain: 'x'
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.range-input {
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.rail {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
}

.handle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1);
  width: 24px;
}

.handle:hover {
  cursor: grab;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1.2);
}

.handle:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.min {
  left: 0;
}

.max {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" class="range-input">
  <div class="rail"></div>
  <div id="min" class="handle min"></div>
  <div id="max" class="handle max"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your elements are registering an event handler that is listening for drag events on the document. Your logic contains no exclusions, so a click and drag action anywhere in the window will trigger your logic.

I can see what you're trying to prevent, though. I think you want to ensure that when the mouse leaves a handle during the drag action (either up or down) the drag action continues firing. To do that, register your mousedown event on the element. You can still register your drag events with the document, but move them into your event handler for mousedown, like so:

```js
function draggable(selector, options) {
  var options = options || {};
  let el = document.querySelector(selector);
  var mx = 0,
    my = 0;
  var dragging = false;
  var offset = [0, 0];
  var constrain = options.constrain || false;
  if (options === undefined) options = [];

  el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    offset = {
      x: el.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
      y: el.offsetTop - e.clientY
    };
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      mx = e.clientX;
      my = e.clientY;

      if (dragging) {
        if (!constrain || constrain == 'x') el.style.left = (mx + offset.x) + 'px';
        if (!constrain || constrain == 'y') el.style.top = (my + offset.y) + 'px';
      }
    });
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
      dragging = false;
    });
  });
}
var min = new draggable('#min', {
  constrain: 'x'
});
var max = new draggable('#max', {
  constrain: 'x'
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.range-input {
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.rail {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
}

.handle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1);
  width: 24px;
}

.handle:hover {
  cursor: grab;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1.2);
}

.handle:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.min {
  left: 0;
}

.max {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" class="range-input">
  <div class="rail"></div>
  <div id="min" class="handle min"></div>
  <div id="max" class="handle max"></div>
</div>
```

Note that you'll need to unregister your document event handlers when you've finished dragging. I haven't added that logic, but it's not hard.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks JDB!

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - Yeah... I mentioned unregistering the event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

For the `mousedown` only, you should check if the clicked element was indeed the one you want

```js
function draggable(selector, options) {
  var options = options || {};
  let el = document.querySelector(selector);
  var mx = 0,
    my = 0;
  var dragging = false;
  var offset = [0, 0];
  var constrain = options.constrain || false;
  if (options === undefined) options = [];

  el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    offset = {
      x: el.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
      y: el.offsetTop - e.clientY
    };
  });
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mx = e.clientX;
    my = e.clientY;

    if (dragging) {
      if (!constrain || constrain == 'x') el.style.left = (mx + offset.x) + 'px';
      if (!constrain || constrain == 'y') el.style.top = (my + offset.y) + 'px';
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    dragging = false;
  });
}
var min = new draggable('#min', {
  constrain: 'x'
});
var max = new draggable('#max', {
  constrain: 'x'
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.range-input {
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.rail {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
}

.handle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1);
  width: 24px;
}

.handle:hover {
  cursor: grab;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1.2);
}

.handle:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.min {
  left: 0;
}

.max {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" class="range-input">
  <div class="rail"></div>
  <div id="min" class="handle min"></div>
  <div id="max" class="handle max"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works too, though moving the mousemove event registration into the mousedown event handler is probably going to be more scalable. Too many mousemove event handlers get expensive for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to obtain a larger area for dragging the div elements. I created a background div of class `container` that is larger than the div to be dragged and transparent

```
.container {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1);
}
```

```js
function draggable(selector, options) {
  var options = options || {};
  let el = document.querySelector(selector);
  var mx = 0,
    my = 0;
  var dragging = false;
  var offset = [0, 0];
  var constrain = options.constrain || false;
  if (options === undefined) options = [];

  el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    offset = {
      x: el.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
      y: el.offsetTop - e.clientY
    };
  });
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mx = e.clientX;
    my = e.clientY;

    if (dragging) {
      if (!constrain || constrain == 'x') el.style.left = (mx + offset.x) + 'px';
      if (!constrain || constrain == 'y') el.style.top = (my + offset.y) + 'px';
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    dragging = false;
  });
}
var min = new draggable('#min', {
  constrain: 'x'
});
var max = new draggable('#max', {
  constrain: 'x'
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.range-input {
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}

.rail {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1);
}

.handle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1);
  width: 24px;
}

.container:hover {
  cursor: grab;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) scale(1.2);
}

.container:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.min {
  left: 0;
}

.max {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" class="range-input">
  <div class="rail"></div>
  <div id="min" class="container min">
    <div class="handle min"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="max" class="container max">
    <div class="handle max"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This gets ugly when the handles are too close to each other. You could conceivably add some logic to check for overlap and reduce the container's left/right size accordingly.